# Uber API authentication is flaky

Tags: curl, uber-api

I have been having a tough time trying to get authentication to reliably work.

I am using node.js, express, passport to get an access token. I am able to construct a cURL URL from the commandline using the access token to access most resources. However, when I request the /v1/request endpoint I get an error:

```
{ message: 'Invalid OAuth 2.0 credentials provided.', 2015-05-05T02:15:35.457072+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'unauthorized' }
```

I have gotten the same cURL command to work before and then all of a sudden it stopped working (after updating it to use a new auth token).

Would love some insight into ways to diagnose the issue - but auth seems to be working in general but not for the request endpoint. Here is the cURL URL I am using:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE" -d "{\"scope\":\"request\", \"start_longitude\":\"-122.31709\", \"start_latitude\":\"47.613940\",\"product_id\":\"6450cc0f-4d39-4473-8632-1e2c2049fefe\"}"
```

Comment: `after updating it to use a new auth token` Well the error message says "unauthorized", and you are getting that error message since you updated the auth token.  Are you saying that works with curl *with the new access token*?  If so, suggest you edit your question to make that clearer.

Comment: Have you seen Google's [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)? I found it useful to walk through all the steps.